# React Native - Click on scrollview items during setInterval()

Tags: react-native, scrollview, requestanimationframe

I have a simple **ScrollView** (*scrolling horizontal*) with some items that each have a TouchableOpacity around them.
The *onPress*-method for them is just a **console.log** so I can see the output.
So far it works!

But I then have made a **setInterval()** that on each loop makes a **scrollTo({x:xValue, y:0, animated:false})** on the ScrollView that increases the X-value.

This way I get like a Newsticker look and feel and it is scrolling nicely.
But when it runs, the click on each item stop working?!

I guess it has something to do with the time set for setInterval(func, time) because when I increase it to a high value it works (*but ofcourse the scrolling is not nice*).

So I tried made a loop-method that uses requestAnimationFrame() like below, but still nothing happens when I click on the items:

```
function loop(func, throttle) {
let running;
let speed = throttle || 0;
function insideLoop() {
    if (running !== false) {
        requestAnimationFrame(insideLoop);
        speed--;
        if(speed <= 0){
          running = func();
          speed = throttle || 0;
        }
    }
}
insideLoop();
}
```

Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: You might be blocking the UI thread. Can you show all the relevant code?